# python multi-processing queue: is putting independent from getting?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

Is `putting` an object in a **[multi-processing queue](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)** independent from `getting` an object from it?

In other words, will `putting` an object block the process **P1** if another process **P2** is `getting` from it?

**Update:** I am assuming an *infinite* queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reading of the source code is that `get` obtains a read lock, which is independent of of the lock (called `_notempty`) acquired by `put`. If I understand correctly, concurrent `get`s can block each other, and concurrent `put`s can block each other (modulo your use of the `block` parameter), but that gets and puts do not mutually block.

Comment: re: reading source: that's how I normally go but in this instance I felt lazy.  I read the source code too anyways after reading your reply: the "write" side is decoupled from the "read" side through a a `Pipe`.

Comment: Agh, I see that my comment was (understandably) taken the wrong way. I only meant that the multiprocessing stuff is "pure python", and available with all of the other standard modules. I didn't mean it like "RTFM N00B!". Anyway, I'm glad my answer was helpful. I hope it's correct. :)