# What's the advantage of queues over pipes when communicating between processes?

Tags: python, linux, queue, multiprocessing, pipe

What would be the advantage(s) (if any) of using 2 **[Queues](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)** over a **[Pipe](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe)** to communicate between processes?

I am planning on using the `multiprocessing` python module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The big win is that queues are process- and thread- safe. Pipes are not: if two different processes try to read from or write to the same end of a pipe, bad things happen. Queues are also at a somewhat higher level of abstraction than pipes, which may or may not be an advantage in your specific case.

Comment: Indeed; the multiprocessing queue is implemented as Pipes protected with Locks.

Comment: Jonathan's comment is related to a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275108/python-multi-processing-queue-is-putting-independent-from-getting/

Answer (score 4):

Queues hold the messages and retains them until the next time the queue is active and pushes it through...regardless if the pipe or connection is broken...with a pipe/connection, its goodbye to the message with an error...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.