# Is RabbitMQ or Kafka message queue a 1:1 messaging system?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, ipc, message-queue

As mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2288120/3317808),

> A message queue is a one-way pipe: one process writes to the queue, and another reads the data in the order

SysV message queue is one example

---

So, my understanding is,

one message queue is used by two processes, where one process(producer) insert an item in the queue and another process(consumer) consumes the item from the queue

---

1) Is RabbitMQ or Kafka message queue a 1:1 messaging system? used by **only** two  processes, where one process writes and other process reads......

2) after the consumer consume the item, does the item get deleted? If no, why do we need queue data structure? Why not just shared memory?

Comment: Kafka stores an immutable log of records that are written by processes called producers and read by processes called consumers. That fits pretty closely to your definition. I've never heard 1:1 messaging system used as a term before but in the case of Kafka, a record can be written only once but read many times, by many different consumers who don't have to know anything about each other. This is one aspect that makes it somewhat different from rabbitmq.

Comment: @dawsaw say there are 10 consumers, so, do you mean, an element in Kafka message queue will not get deleted until all 10 consumers consume? How does that work?

Comment: It won't be deleted until the broker (server side) deletes it based on the retention policy, which may be time or size based. The consumers don't have any say over when the records are deleted from the queue, that's all done on the broker itself. I believe this is a key difference with traditional message queues like rabbitmq

Comment: @dawsaw So, what significant about maintaining queue, when the items don't get deleted? Why not just maintain some map or shared memory?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is not strictly 1:1 messaging system. Multiple producers can write into a topic and multiple consumers can read from it. Moreover, in Kafka, multiple consumers can be assigned same or different consumer groups. Every message is consumed by only one consumer from every consumer group (load balancing) and all consumer groups receive a copy of every message (of course, if they are subscribed to corresponding topics and no messages are lost). A good description of this process can be found in this article: [Scalability of Kafka Messaging using Consumer Groups](https://blog.cloudera.com/scalability-of-kafka-messaging-using-consumer-groups).

In Kafka all messages are persisted on the disk and stored until the [compaction](https://medium.com/swlh/introduction-to-topic-log-compaction-in-apache-kafka-3e4d4afd2262) reaps it, or the `retention.ms` passes, or the log size is exceeded. That's a very high-level point of view and there are a lot of nuances here. Like: the messages are stored in segments, every segment contains multiple messages. When the retention period passes for a message, it is not removed from the segment at that moment, instead Kafka waits until all messages in that segment are expired and delete the whole segment at once. Also, retention could come before the log exceeds the maximum size or vice versa: the log can exceed the size even before the retention period passes. And so on. Just read the [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation) and pay attention to topics about "log cleaner" and "retention".

After the Kafka consumer reads the message it is neither compacted, nor expired. So, it's not removed from the log and stays there. It also means that every message could be re-read by a consumer if needed (until it is deleted completely). It can be useful if some of your consumers went offline for some reason and were not able to process the messages as they come in. It also allows interesting features like transaction replays and so on. Persistence is one of the Kafka's features.

Shared memory? Well, strictly speaking shared memory is only allowed inside a single process. So you can't generally use "shared memory" when you need to access it from different processes. And there is absolutely no way to have "shared memory" when you app runs on multiple hosts. However, there are in-memory brokers. Like Redis can be used as a message broker, and it's all in-memory. However, if such a broker restarts for some reason you lose everything. Speaking about Redis: it has [two persistence configurations](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) specifically to handle the restarts.

I am not sure about RabbitMQ, but it probably deletes messages after the consumer acknowledged them by default. So it's closer to 1:1 mental model. However, RabbitMQ [employs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html) disk persistence as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214789/discussion-on-answer-by-madhead-is-rabbitmq-or-kafka-message-queue-a-11-messagi).